# Adding an Identity Column to an Entity Generated from a SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a Web API project that inputs results from our SQL server into our internal messenger using /commands.

I have created my Web API, and I Created a ADO.NET Entity Model that is auto generated based on a table from my SQL server. The SQL server identity column is a GUID# but i would like to add another property to my entity that is simply an incrementing integer.

I added the Scalar property to my integer and set it as:

Default Value = 1

Entity Key = true

Nullable = false

StoreGeneratedpattern = Identity

Type = Int32

It gives me errors when building and publishing and will not work.

Any thoughts on maybe what i have done wrong?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: So the entire entity is generated automatically from the SQL Table. The manually added column is called ID.

Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line283: Must specicfy mapping for all key properties of the EntitySet.

Comment: Also Error 11009: Property 'ID' is not mapped.

Comment: So you have two Entity Keys? The new one and the GUID?

Comment: The errors occur only with the new one selected as Entity.
*EDIT*
Scratch that I did have both selected, the Error3024 stays but I am not seeing the 11009 error when building/publishing.

Comment: When the model was created does that property have a [DatabaseGenerated] attribute on it?

Comment: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

Comment: That property was added after the model was created and that property does not exist in the table on the SQL server.